# Drupal: Which MySQL do I need?

Tags: database, drupal, windows-7, package

this might sounds silly but I am super confused.
I want to install drupal on localhost but I need to install a SQL database for it too.

Which database package do I get (for free) ?
I went to MySQL website but I do not understand which one I need to download, or if mysql at all.. ?

I have win 7 32 bit and I only care that drupal is installed on my machine and for me to see, don't care about outside world, don't want to webhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an [excellent video on installing Drupal](http://www.slideshare.net/a_rupeshkumar/installation-of-drupal-on-windows-xp-with-xampp-presentation) on your home windows machine for personal use. It uses [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and it works GREAT. XAMPP installs and configures WAMP environment for you, one click, no hastle. Wow, this made everything so simple and easy, one click! (and a very long wait for file extraction XD )

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get Drupal up and running, you should take the **[Aquia stack installer](http://acquia.com/downloads)**, it will install all the things you need, so you want have to deal with the fuss of installing MySQL and all the other things needed. It only works for 32 bit windows, but that's no issue for you.

**Edit to clarify mac's misunderstanding**

- Aquia stack installer installs what acquia calls DAMP. Drupal Apache MySQL PHP. It also installs phpmyadmin and few other things. The perfect 1 click drupal install on a clean box.
- Aquia Drupal is a package including Drupal core and the most used contrib modules like CCK, Views, Date and many more. This package is tested to make sure all modules integrate and if a bug is introduced in a module they will usuallly either fix it or use a bugfree version. This is like a normal drupal install and requires a stack like WAMP, LAMP, MAMP or alike.
- Acquai is started by Drupal's creator, so their staff has some of the best Drupal experts.

Comment: Nice find, did not know about that! (+1)

Comment: Actually, after having upvoted your answer, I realised that on Acquia's site is written: **"Requires PHP, a webserver and a database."** So it might not be what you intended, or at least not what I understood from your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the mysql community server.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html

You should look at a tutorial to install Drupal because you'll need also a web server(Apache) and php.

Good luck!